# node.js simple tcp test

Tags: macos, node.js, tcp

here is the code you can find every where on net

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write("Echo server\r\n");
  socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

A simple tcp server will echo whatever you will send it. How to send data to it? What tools/commands I need in mac to test this server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`nc` aka `netcat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc). In Terminal.app, while your node app is running:

```
$ nc localhost 1337
Echo server
```

Ta-da!